# What does "attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'" mean?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
    local item = RS:WaitForChild("Pencil")
    local price = 350
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local stats = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
    
    if stats.Strength.Value>=price then
        stats.Strength.Value = stats.Strength.Value - price
        local cloned = item:Clone()
        cloned.Parent = player.Backpack
        cloned.Parent = player.StarterGear
    end
end)
```

I am trying to make a shop and it comes up with "attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'" on line 6:

```
local stats = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
```

I copied it exactly how the video had it and the video had no problem and apparently player has no value even though we set it up just one line above

Comment: You can't get a LocalPlayer in a ServerScript; try doing it again

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are indexing a `nil` value, which means that `player` value is `nil`, which means that `game.Players.LocalPlayer` on the previous like returns `nil`. Why that is you need to figure out, as there is not much to go by.

The [example](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Players/LocalPlayer) shows that it should be `local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer`, so you may want to try that.

Comment: I tried to put in what you told me to but it came with the same error as before.